# Nginx/Apache2 httpd and Tomcat 7 on Pivotal CloudFoundry

Tags: tomcat, nginx, apache2, cloud-foundry

What is the best way to configure a web server in front of a Tomcat Instance on CloudFoundry?

I have been tasked to research the best way to put a web server in front of a Tomcat instance on PCF. Mostly to rewrite URLs (Trying to remove the application context path from the URL for a multi site application)

The main issue that I am encountering is that except for the embedded web server (Jetty) that is bundled as part of the java build pack it does not contain any other web server NGINX or Apache2. I would think this is a very common scenario in existing applications. I know that the staticfile buildpack contains NGINX and the PHP buildpack contains Apache2 - Does this mean that I have to fork the java-buildpack and customize the buildpack to fit my needs?

Also, how do I get around modifying the httpd.conf - Is it the same approach as what is the documents - Basically adding my configuration files under .my-customized-buildpack/httpd (or nginx)/*.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to configure a web server in front of a Tomcat Instance on CloudFoundry?

This doesn't apply for the poster, but for others reading this it's critical to consider *why* you want to do this.  If you're just looking for load balancing, you **don't** need to do this.  The CF platform automatically handles load balancing and this is why the Java build pack does not add Nginx or Apache HTTPD by default.

> Mostly to rewrite URLs (Trying to remove the application context path from the URL for a multi site application)

Have you considered the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).  This is a very good way to rewrite URLs without requiring another server.  It's also been around for a long time and is battle tested.

Another option might be to use a [route service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html#user-provided) ([more here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/route-binding.html)).  This is a capability provided by the CF platform and allows you to intercept incoming requests and adjust them.  It's similar to a Java Servlet Filter, but at a higher layer.  You just have a second app which acts like the Filter, and the platform handles routing requests to the "filter" app and your original app.  Links above explain this in more detail.

Having said that, I would still suggest UrlRewriteFilter over a route service, as long as the filter will work for you because the filter is a lighter weight solution.

You could also look at forking / customizing the build pack, but IMHO this is even more complicated and it has ongoing maintenance burden (you now have to keep your build pack fork up-to-date).

> The main issue that I am encountering is that except for the embedded web server (Jetty) that is bundled as part of the java build pack it does not contain any other web server NGINX or Apache2.

While this is common outside of CF, it's not generally necessary in CF.  The platform itself provides load balancing, which is the main reason for such a setup.  On CF, if you also added Nginx or Apache HTTPD, you'd end up with an extra unnecessary hop in the request path.

By default:  browser -> load balancer -> gorouters -> your app (tomcat / jetty)

What you're trying to do:  browser -> load balancer -> gorouters -> Nginx / HTTPD -> your app (tomcat / jetty)

Plus the platform is better suited to making load balancing decisions anyway, because it knows when you scale up and down your app instances.

Please consider very carefully if it's necessary to add this extra hop.  It adds latency, complexity and another possible failure vector.

> I know that the staticfile buildpack contains NGINX and the PHP buildpack contains Apache2

Nginx & HTTPD are included in these build pack's because it's the primary way to serve up content via HTTP.  Newer versions of PHP have a built-in web server, but it's not recommended for production usage so we still rely on Nginx or HTTPD to handle the HTTP requests and pass them off to PHP (via FastCGI).

> Also, how do I get around modifying the httpd.conf - Is it the same approach as what is the documents - Basically adding my configuration files under .my-customized-buildpack/httpd (or nginx)/*.conf?

Sorry, I don't understand your question here. You said you were using a Java app above, so there wouldn't be any HTTPD or Nginx config.  Are you trying to fork and customize the Java build pack?  If so, that's probably worthy of it's own question.

Hope that helps!